# Change color text in windows cmd not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I want to change color of text. And when I try it in VS code it works.
But when I try it in CMD in Windows I get this:

```
←[91mstring
```

Code in python:

```py
print ('\033[91m' + "string")
```

Comment: Have a look also at https://stackoverflow.com/q/287871/4046632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "bug" in cmd. You need to first clear the screen with:

```py
import os
os.system("cls")
```

Than it should work.

Full code:

```py
import os
os.system("cls")

print('\033[91m' + "string")
```

I hope my answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use it properly :

```
import os
os.system("cls")

print('\033[91m' + "string")
```

There is also the [Python termcolor module](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/). Usage is pretty simple:

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored('string', 'red'), colored('string', 'green'))
```